# CMD: `DIR *.ext` and `FOR ... (*.ext)` matches too much

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In Windows Command Shell, how do I get a FOR loop or DIR command to match *only* the file extension pattern provided? Or said another way, how to do non-greedy extension matching?

For example, a directory contains `floo.tif`, `floorbar.tiff`, `floormatic.tifw` and I only want to operate on `floo.tif`

```
for %%a in (floo*.tif) do @echo %%a
```

results in:

```
floo.tif
floorbar.tiff
floormatic.tifw
```

and this is the desired result:

```
floo.tif
```

`dir *.tif` has the same result.

Comment: Maybe the 8.3 representation of the file names matches your pattern? I think `floorbar.tiff`'s internal representation could be `floorb~1.tif`.

Comment: @C-Otto, thanks. You're right, the pattern matching does appear to be conducted against the 8.3 names. So now I understand the why, next is to find out how cope with it.

Comment: You could pipe the output out dir to findstr to match by regexp.  I'm on my cell phone right now do I dare not hazard a full answer, but if no one has answers by the time I get to a PC I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

What I had in mind was this:

```
dir /b | findstr /i "^floo.*\.tif$"
```

or

```
dir /b floo*.tif | findstr /i "tif$"
```

Either would prevent matching .tiff and .tifw, giving you the result you expected.

The regexp vocabulary of `findstr` is severely limited.  For instance, you can't do `\w` to match word characters, and `(foo|bar|baz)` notation is not supported.  But at least it offers more granular control than standard wildcard matching.  Do `findstr /?` to see what syntax is supported.

```
for /f "delims=:" %%I in ('dir /b floo*.tif ^| findstr /i "tif$"') do (
    rem process each %%I match
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Win32 command-line utility for finding filenames that I wrote a long time ago, and since it matches the long filename it does not suffer from that problem:
[vfind.exe](http://david.tribble.com/programs.html#vfind). (Source code is also available for it.)

I use it like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('vfind floo*.tif') do @echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%a in (
  'dir /b /a-d floo*.tif^|findstr /ix "floo.*\.tif"'
) do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing for the project at hand, though next time I would consider using @Loadmaster's vfind or findstr as recommended by @dbenham and @rojo.

```
for %%a in (*.tif) do (
  if /i "%%~xa"==".tif" @echo Doing something to %%a...
  )
```

The advantage of `if` is not needing to run any other programs, so it's faster, more compact to write and easier to mentally decode later. The advantage of vfind is it's complete straightforwardness and clarity, while findstr provides more control in the pattern matching.